# Unable to Install gvim/dependency in local directory without super user permission

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

Wanted to install gvim in the local drives as I don't have the root permission but it does install the GUI version [i.e. GVIM] of it.

Steps Followed:

1. First I tried doing the ./configure process with just the --prefix to local directory and said no GUI related things are compiled. Then understood that by default GUI is disabled.
2. Next in the src/Makefile I enabled the GUI option to use the GTK2 version of the GUI and also  updated the prefix to include local directory. Then downloaded some packages called "gtk-vim-syntax" which contained some .vim files related to gtk2, gtk3, gnome etc. added that path to $PATH. Then first tried running the below configure option

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/home/installed --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2
   ```
3. But still when I saw the configure terminal outputs it said no--enable-gui found, so no GUI enabled.
4. Then when checked online they said, you need to first install vim-common packages and either vim-gtk or vim-gnome and everyone provide the option of sudo apt-install etc etc. but since I am not the root user I am unable to install that way. Is there anyplace where I can find those package and install them locally before I try to ./configure in the vim folder ?

Or is there any other way I can install the gvim and all its dependent files in the local directory and not as root user ? Why can't they add some notes/info on how to install the dependencies locally as well in the README.

Kindly let me know if anyone had overcome this issue. Thanks in advance !

Update:

1. I do see the gtk-2 is installed in the following path /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0 but not sure why the ./configure isnt auto picking it.

Do I need to set any environment variable so that the ./configure picks it up ?

Comment: It's a really good question, IMHO, and I'm surprised that it hadn't seen any upvotes after a few days when it came up in my review queue.  It could be that you'll find this question is a better fit for the audience on [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) rather than Super User.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for your suggestion. Have posted the question in the other group.